# Gitolite Wildcards not Working

Tags: git, gitolite

I'm trying to use wildcards in my Gitolite v3 installation, but it's not working. When I push the gitolite.conf file with the wildcard definitions, it actually creates folders called "CREATOR", as opposed to using it as a wildcard. If I try to create a repository as a user, I get an error that the repo doesn't exist. Well of course it doesn't, I'm trying to create it!

Here's the relevant definition in gitolite.conf:

## individual homework script repositories

```
repo  f12/csci442/CREATOR/scripts
  C   = @f12_csci442
  RW+ = CREATOR @s12_csci442_wheel
```

When I try to create a repo as a user in the @f12_csci442 group, I'm told

```
FATAL: R any f12/csci442/twhitney/scripts twhitney DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Well, I found the answer. Sitaram Chamarty, the creator of Gitolite, got back to me really quickly on the Gitolite Google Group, so first of thanks Sitaram!

In case anyone else runs into this problem:

`The rules for how to determine if something is a real repo or a wild card pattern changed subtly.  TBH I never expected someone to have a wild card pattern that does not contain a wildcard.  At this point, this will not change.
You ought to be able to fool it by turning it into a regex, like so:

    repo foo/CREATOR/script[s]`

Comment: You should post this answer as a real answer and accept it instead of posting it as a comment. Welcome to SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the variable `GL_WILDREPOS` to 1 (in `~/gitolite.rc`)?

Comment: Wildcard repos are enabled by default in v3: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2migr.html